# Petites capitales dans les mononymes et particules nobilaires

Tags: noms-propres, typographie, majuscules

*Comme l’éditeur de StackExchange ne permet pas le rendu des petites capitales, celles-ci seront signalées dans la suite par du gras.*

L’on préconise l’usage des [petites capitales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petite_capitale) pour les patronymes comme dans « Jean-Jacques **Rousseau** ».

Mais il me semble qu’il faille aussi les utiliser pour les [mononymes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mononyme) tel **Platon**, **Voltaire**, **Lénine**, ou **Madona**. Qu’en est-il ?

Enfin, pour les particules nobillaires, doit-on écrire « Jean Le Rond **d'Alembert** » ou bien « d’**Alembert** » ?

Comment: Les initiales des noms propres n'étant pas des petites capitales mais des majuscules, elles ne devraient pas être en gras dans ta question. R**ousseau**, P**laton**, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rien n'interdit d'utiliser des petites capitales utf-8 dans StackExchange, mais c'est assez fastidieux (copier/coller de lettres individuelles).

> Bᴀᴜᴅᴇʟᴀɪʀᴇ (Charles), Les Fleurs du mal, Paris, Poulet-Malassis et De Broise, 1re éd., 1857
> Rᴏᴜꜱꜱᴇᴀᴜ (Jean-Jacques)

Sinon, tu peux aussi utiliser une combinaison d'indice et d'exposant pour simuler les petites capitales , mais la taille et l'alignement laissent alors à désirer :

> R<sub><sup>OUSSEAU</sup></sub> (Jean-Jacques), écrit avec le code suivant : `R<sub><sup>OUSSEAU</sup></sub>`

Les mononymes utilisent normalement la même fonte que les patronymes, ne serait-ce que par souci de cohérence.

Les particules nobiliaires ne sont généralement pas en capitales.

> *Les petites capitales ne sont pas des majuscules ! La preuve… dans
> un groupe de mots composé en petites capitales, les majuscules se
> composent en grandes capitales :
>
> **Jean de Lᴀ Fᴏɴᴛᴀɪɴᴇ**.*
>
> Jean-Pierre Lacroix, *Orthotypographie*, 2007.